# Play only one SWF file at a time

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

How can I stop one SWF file playing when playing another in a HTML page?

I currently have a carousel that displays multiple SWF files and I don't want any overlapping of video or audio. I've been looking into LocalConnection and JavaScript options but with no luck.
My SWF files are currently ActionScript 3 and Flash Player 10.
I have a large play button on them, with the ActionScript code:

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
import fl.video.VideoState;

video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.STATE_CHANGE,showButton);
playVideoButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,playVideo);

function playVideo(event:MouseEvent):void {
    video.play();
    playVideoButton.visible=false;
}

function showButton(event:VideoEvent):void {
    switch (event.target.state) {
        case "stopped" :
            playVideoButton.visible=true;
            break;
        case "playing" :
            playVideoButton.visible=false;
            break;
        case "paused" :
            playVideoButton.visible=true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to incoporate a "stop the other SWF files playing" in this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll want to do is set up an `ExternalInterface` callback method in each SWF file. That will allow JavaScript to call a function within your SWF file.

So for instance, you could set up a function called `stopPlaying()` and that's that.

Then, you set up a JavaScript function called `playVideo(string:String)` that calls `stopPlaying()` on every SWF file except the one that is associated with the string that you pass in.

Whenever someone hits play in one of your SWF files, do `ExternalInterface.call("playVideo", "myString")` and your JavaScript function should work.

Comment: Thanks Myk, I'm just trying to get my head around it now, I understand what your saying, I just need to work out what goes where - I'll report back with my findings - thanks for your help.